# ARCore Android Studio: Can i change or remove this icon when is searching ground?

Tags: android, arcore

Im making an ar app and when i open the sceneform i have this icon always: 
[image]

Can i change that icon or remove that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PlaneDiscoveryController](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/PlaneDiscoveryController) and setInstructionView(View view) method.
You can remove the view by using the following:

```
ArFragment.getDiscoveryController().hide();
ArFragment.getDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(null);
```